# How to apply existing indenting rules to new file type?

Tags: vimrc, indentation, filetype

I've been happily using vim for years for C and C++ projects. My code formatting/indentation rules have been cobbled together over the years based on solutions to at-the-time needs...which is to say, I'm no expert at `.vimrc` syntax, so I couldn't articulate why it works correctly for C and C++ projects, just *that* it does.

Once in a while I'll have to deal with a Makefile or CMakeLists.txt, and because that's so infrequent, I usually deal manually with any need for indentation adjustment.

Recently, though, I'm having to deal with Jenkins Pipeline Scripts. The filenames are typically simply `Jenkinsfile`, i.e. no extension. Broadly speaking, the files themselves follow what Wikipedia calls "[the one true brace style, variant 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Variant:_1TBS_(OTBS))"

**Is there a way I can have vim apply my current indentation rules for C/C++ to files named `Jenkinsfile`?**

---

My current `.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

set termguicolors
 if has('nvim')
" https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ
set guicursor=n-v-c:block-Cursor/lCursor-blinkon0,i-ci:ver25-Cursor/lCursor,r-cr:hor20-Cursor/lCursor
endif

filetype plugin on
colorscheme Base2Tone_MorningDark
"colorscheme Base2Tone_DrawbridgeDark
"colorscheme Base2Tone_LavenderDark
"colorscheme Base2Tone_PoolDark
"colorscheme Base2Tone_SuburbDark

set expandtab                   " Expand tab to spaces
set hlsearch
set number                      " Line numbers
" set ruler

set backspace=indent,eol,start
set cino=(0                     " Indent N chars from the line w/ unclosed paren
set laststatus=2                " Status-line always
set scrolloff=4                 " Start scrolling when cursor is N lines from top/bottom
set shiftwidth=2                " Number of spaces for each step of autoindent
set softtabstop=2               " Number of spaces that <tab> counts for
set textwidth=80

set statusline=
set statusline+=\%F
set statusline+=\%=%l/%L        " Line n/N
set statusline+=%4v             " virtual column
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

set formatoptions+=q            " Allow formatting of comments with "gq"
set formatoptions+=t            " Auto-wrap using textwidth, auto-insert comment leader
set formatoptions+=j            " Remove comment leader when joining lines

set t_ut=

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 1
let g:syntastic_c_config_file = '.syntastic_c_config'
"let g:syntastic_debug = 1
"let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
```

With this `.vimrc`, vim seems to apply *no* indentation rules to `Jenkinsfile`s. I.e. whenever I hit Enter, despite any existing indendtation of curly-brace, vim takes me to column 0 of the next line.

Comment: What does `:verbose set filetype?` report in a `Jenkinsfile`? You could probably trim down the reproducibility with [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604). You probably need to detect `Jenkinsfile` as some filetype (*e.g.*, `jenkins`) and then add a local ftplugin (*e.g.*, `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/jenkins.vim`) which `setlocal`s `cindent` or similar. (PS You have `filetype plugin on` in your vimrc twice. Also `formatoptions` is buffer-local and unfortunately many ftplugins mess with it, so you may find that your settings get overwritten.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - `:verbose set filetype` responds with `filetype=`, i.e. "filetype", an equals-sign, then end-of-string (or whitespace only).